# aSmack MUC room does not exist

Tags: android, xmpp

I am making an android chat application using the aSmack 8-0.8.10 library. I got trying to implement MultiUserChat.

So the set up I have so far is an openfire server running on localhost, and a spark client for testing purposes on local host as well. I message back and forth from my android client to my spark client to test new features.

I can successfully create a room and join it, but when i send the invite to the Spark client and they try to join, it shows "The room you are trying to enter does not exist" The room also appears under Actions-> Join Conference Room.

Note: I have initialized the aSmack static classes with SmackAndroid.init(this)
and called SmackAndroid.onDestroy in the service onDestory method

Here is the code i am trying this with:

```
MultiUserChat muc = new MultiUserChat(connection, "myroom@conference.localhost");
    try {
        muc.create("thing1");
        muc.sendConfigurationForm(new Form(Form.TYPE_SUBMIT));
        muc.join("thing1");
        //muc.getParticipants();
        muc.invite("test1@localhost", "Join My Group");

        Log.d("XMPP","People: "+ muc.getParticipants().toString());
        //^^returns an empty list

        muc.sendMessage("This is a test");

    } catch (XMPPException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

EDIT: Some Stanzas since a user requested them.

http://pastebin.com/7AxmQaDb

EDIT2:SOLVED

Basically i solved this problem by removing the muc.join("thing1") line. It seems that when a user creates a room they automatically join, without the need for the join call.

Comment: Could you get hold of the actual XMPP stanzas being exchanged between the client and the server?  I'd suspect that the first client isn't setting up the room correctly somehow, but it's hard to tell for sure.

Comment: Please see the updated post. Its what i was able to get from the debugger.